# CakePHP cache permissions issues

Tags: cakephp, caching

This week I have moved a CakePHP application on the server so that it is served from C:\path\current\ where current is a symlink to C:\path\versions[date]. Previously the app was in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

Thus each time I deploy changes, I make a new version of the app and the deploy script updates the symlink. In order to avoid having to re-create the temp dir each time, I've moved the temp dir to C:\path\app_tmp\ - the deploy script drops a symlink at app\tmp pointing to this temp dir.

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 and the web server is IIS7. C:\path\app_tmp\ has full permissions (Everyone has Full Control).

Since making the change to the location of the app and the tmp dir, users are reporting sporadic instances of warnings appearing at the top of the page. The app is in debug=0 but these do not appear in the error log.

Examples:

> Warning:
>   unlink(C:\path\app_tmp\cache\models\prefix_cake_model_default_app_modelname):
>   Permission denied in
>   C:\path\versions[date]\www\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php on
>   line 254
>
> Warning:
>   SplFileInfo::openFile(C:\path\versions[date]\www\app\tmp\cache\models\prefix_cake_model_default_app_modelname):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\path\versions[date]\www\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php on
>   line 313

(actual paths/model names obfuscated)

Here is what I have in core.php:

```
$engine = 'File';
$duration = '+999 days';
if (Configure::read('debug') >= 1) {
    $duration = '+10 seconds';
}
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $prefix = 'cmd_';
}
else {
    $prefix = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '_';
}

Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));
```

I have this in bootstrap.php:

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

Any suggestions? I have a feeling that perhaps the permissions aren't being inherited properly from the app\tmp symlink to the actual tmp dir, but on the other hand the error logs seem to write correctly and these errors are only sporadic.

One idea i had was to switch to using Wincache but then I can't find any information on how I clear the model cache when I've got a database change to deploy (currently I can just clear the model cache with a grunt task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to resolve this while sticking to using the default file caching. I've switched the application to using Wincache. To clear model cache when a database change is made, I've written a short script to execute:

```
Cache::clear('_cake_model_');
```

This has to be done in the browser because CLI uses a different cache from IIS, but I've made it "gruntable" by using grunt-shell and just executing: `start http://script/location/clear_cache`